# Subscription system in redis

Tags: redis, node-redis

I'm looking to build a subscription system using redis. I was thinking about to put a key with the subscription ending date as an expire time and then using redis keyspace notifications to proceed to remove/renew subscription based on that but I was reading about Pub/Sub reliability and found out it hasn't. So I don't know if it's the best choice for a subscription system.

Is there a better approach to accomplish this using redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis has specific commands to implement a subscription system:

https://redis.io/topics/pubsub when you don't need persistence
https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro when you need persistence (since 5.0)